# Cannot autoscroll using middle mouse button when using Adobe Reader for PDFs

Tags: pdf, mouse, adobe-acrobat, scrolling, adobe-reader

On every web page I visit, and also when I am reading one of my outlook emails and also whenever I am reading a Word document, simply by clicking and releasing the middle button on my mouse I can then move up and down whichever of these pages I am reading (on web, email or Word), at any speed at all I wish, and also stop and restart the up and down movement instantly, exactly as I wish by just moving the mouse itself up and down. I can achieve this brilliant functionality simply by clicking and releasing the middle button on my mouse, thereafter no clicking or holding or anything else at all is required, I simply move the mouse itself up and down to read the respective page/s exactly as I wish. I find this means of control when reading any page/s indispensably brilliant.

When I am reading a PDF I have opened using Adobe Acrobat Reader however, I have to click and hold down the middle button the entire time I am reading down, say, a 60 page document, to move it up and down (or continually have to keep pressing and holding the button down repeatedly every time I wish to move the page up or down). I am aware of the auto scrolling option in Adobe which is completely inferior to using my normal method above. Can anybody advise how I can get my usual above mentioned functionality which I can use everywhere else except on Adobe opened PDFs please. I know the same question was asked on an Adobe community, thanks for your help in advance.  https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/mouse-autoscrolling/m-p/11128736

Comment: Unclear: do you mean when using the **web browser** to view a PDF file, or when using another tool, such as Adobe Acrobat, Adobe Reader, Sumatra, PDFXChange Editor, Okular or some other tool? Each works differently.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi DrMoishe Pippik, I have now rewritten the entire question to hopefully clarify the problem, my apologies for previous lack of clarity.